# Table value alignment

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, columns

I have a table that looks like this. 
[image]

I generate it using:

```
\begin{table*}
\centering
\caption{ The parameters obtained from the fit for the real-space correlation function \xir{} on the sample with $zcosmo$ and the recovered deprojected correlation function $\xi_{dep}(r)$ for the mock photometric samples} 
\label{tab:table2}
\begin{tabular}{*{5}{c}} 
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|p{2cm}|}{\centering Redshift uncertainty \\ $\left(\frac{\Delta z}{1+zcosmo}\right)$}
& \multicolumn{1}{|p{2cm}|}{\centering $r_{0}$ \\ $(h^{-1}Mpc)$}
& \multicolumn{1}{|p{2cm}|}{\centering $\gamma$} & 
Mass & Fit range \\ 
\hline  
$zcosmo$ & 30.07$\pm$0.66 & 1.8(\textit{fixed}) & $M_{200}>log_{10}(13.7)$ \\ [1ex]
   & 40.16$\pm$4.36 & 1.50$\pm$0.09 & $M_{200}>log_{10}(13.7)$ & 5-50 Mpc \\ [1ex]
0.001 & 32.81$\pm$0.80 & 1.8(\textit{fixed}) & $M_{200}>log_{10}(13.7)$ \\ [1ex]
   & 36.98$\pm$5.93 & 1.67$\pm$0.15 & $M_{200}>log_{10}(13.7)$ & 5-50 Mpc \\ [1ex]
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}
```

As you can see, ***the value in the last column (5-50 Mpc) is aligned with the second row. I want it centred in between the two rows.***

Comment: How is the `\xir` macro defined?

Comment: `\def\xir{$\xi(r)$}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `\multirow` macro (from the `multirow` package).

I would also use the rule-drawing macros of the `booktabs` package, and I'd lose all vertical bars.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,multirow,booktabs,caption}
\newcommand\zcosmo{\textit{zcosmo}}
\begin{document}
\begin{table*}
\centering
\caption{The parameters obtained from the fit for the real-space 
correlation function $\xi(r)$ on the sample with $\zcosmo$ and the 
recovered deprojected correlation function $\xi_{\textit{dep}}(r)$ for 
the mock photometric samples} 
\label{tab:table2}
\begin{tabular}{*{5}{c}} 
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{p{2cm}}{\centering Redshift uncertainty \\ $\bigl(\frac{\Delta z}{1+\zcosmo}\bigr)$}
& \multicolumn{1}{p{2cm}}{\centering $r_{0}$ \\ $(h^{-1}Mpc)$}
& \multicolumn{1}{p{2cm}}{\centering $\gamma$} & 
Mass & Fit range \\ 
\midrule  
$\zcosmo$ & 30.07$\pm$0.66 & 1.8\ (\textit{fixed}) & $M_{200}>\log_{10}(13.7)$ 
             & \multirow{2}{*}{5--50 Mpc}\\ [1ex]
          & 40.16$\pm$4.36 & 1.50$\pm$0.09 & $M_{200}>\log_{10}(13.7)$ &  \\ [1ex]
0.001     & 32.81$\pm$0.80 & 1.8\ (\textit{fixed}) & $M_{200}>\log_{10}(13.7)$ 
             & \multirow{2}{*}{5--50 Mpc}\\ [1ex]
   & 36.98$\pm$5.93 & 1.67$\pm$0.15 & $M_{200}>\log_{10}(13.7)$ & \\ 
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: can you elucidate a bit more on the rule-drawing macros of the booktabs package? What are the vertical bars you are talking about

Comment: @ThePredator - The main rule-drawing macros of the [booktabs](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/booktabs) package are `\toprule`, `\midrule`, `\bottomrule`, and `\cmidrule`. The vertical bars are the ones that get inserted by column specifications such as `|p{2cm}|` -- they're in the code you provided, though not in the screenshot you posted.

Answer (score 2):

- The "5--50 Mpc" can be moved with the help of package `multirow`, see the [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/251953/16967) of Mico.
- Units can be set with package `siunitx`. Especially, they are usually not set in italics. Unit "pc" for parsec is not predefined, but it is easy to add a definition:

  ```
  \DeclareSIUnit{\parsec}{pc}
  ```
- Package `siunitx` also supports table columns with alignment on the decimal dot. As example, columns 2 and 3 are formatted this way.
  The text "(fixed)" instead of the uncertainty is not supported, thus I have put it from the right via `\rlap{(\textit{fixed})}`.
- The math functions like `log` are usually set upright. The example uses macro `\log`.
- The headers with multiple lines are set as inner `tabular`s. This avoids the explicit setting of a width and narrower columns.
- As in Mico's example, the vertical lines are removed and the more professional horizontal lines of package `booktabs` are used.
- The four data entries seem to be two groups, thus I have separated them via `\addlinespace`.

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption} 
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\DeclareSIUnit{\parsec}{pc}
\sisetup{
  range-units=single,
  range-phrase=--,
}
\newcommand*{\xir}{\ensuremath{\xi(r)}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table*}
  \centering
  \caption{ The parameters obtained from the fit for the real-space
  correlation function \xir{} on the sample with $\mathit{zcosmo}$ and the recovered
  deprojected correlation function $\xi_{\text{dep}}(r)$ for the mock
  photometric samples}
  \label{tab:table2}
  \def\fixed{\llap{(\textit{fixed})}}
  \begin{tabular}{
    c
    S[table-format=2.2(2), separate-uncertainty]
    S[table-format=1.2(2), separate-uncertainty]
    cc
  } 
    \toprule
    \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}
      Redshift\\   
      uncertainty\\
      $\left(\frac{\Delta z}{1+zcosmo}\right)$
    \end{tabular}
    & {\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}
        $r_{0}$ \\
        (\si{\per\hour\mega\parsec})
      \end{tabular}}
    & \multicolumn{1}{p{2cm}}{\centering $\gamma$} &
    Mass & Fit range \\
    \midrule
    $\mathit{zcosmo}$ & 30.07+-0.66 & 1.8\fixed & $M_{200}>\log_{10}(13.7)$ &
      \multirow{2}{*}{\SIrange{5}{50}{\mega\parsec}}\\
    & 40.16+-4.36 & 1.50+-0.09 & $M_{200}>\log_{10}(13.7)$ \\
    \addlinespace
    0.001 & 32.81+-0.80 & 1.8\fixed & $M_{200}>\log_{10}(13.7)$ &
      \multirow{2}{*}{\SIrange{5}{50}{\mega\parsec}} \\
    & 36.98+-5.93 & 1.67+-0.15 & $M_{200}>\log_{10}(13.7)$ \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table*}  
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: +1 for letting me know of the `siunitx` package!!